# Unit root testing codes philips perron

Tags: r, unit-testing, integration-testing, time-series

```
PP.test(MxAlberta_Female45,lshort=TRUE)

        Phillips-Perron Unit Root Test

data:  MxAlberta_Female45
Dickey-Fuller = -7.5154, Truncation lag parameter = 3, p-value = 0.01

> PP.test(diff(MxAlberta_Female45))

        Phillips-Perron Unit Root Test

data:  diff(MxAlberta_Female45)
Dickey-Fuller = -20.8186, Truncation lag parameter = 3, p-value = 0.01

> PP.test(MxBC_Female45)

        Phillips-Perron Unit Root Test

data:  MxBC_Female45
Dickey-Fuller = -6.8781, Truncation lag parameter = 3, p-value = 0.01

> adf.test(diff(MxBC_Female45))
Error: could not find function "adf.test"
> 
> PP.test(MxM_Female45)

        Phillips-Perron Unit Root Test

data:  MxM_Female45
Dickey-Fuller = -6.2955, Truncation lag parameter = 3, p-value = 0.01

> PP.test(diff(MxM_Female45))

        Phillips-Perron Unit Root Test

data:  diff(MxM_Female45)
Dickey-Fuller = -17.1554, Truncation lag parameter = 3, p-value = 0.01

> 
> PP.test(MxNB_Female45)

        Phillips-Perron Unit Root Test

data:  MxNB_Female45
Dickey-Fuller = -7.5638, Truncation lag parameter = 3, p-value = 0.01

> PP.test(diff(MxNB_Female45))

        Phillips-Perron Unit Root Test

data:  diff(MxNB_Female45)
Dickey-Fuller = -20.2759, Truncation lag parameter = 3, p-value = 0.01

> 
> MxNL_Female45a<-na.omit(MxNL_Female45)
> PP.test((MxNL_Female45a))
Error in embed(x, 2) : 'x' is not a vector or matrix
> PP.test(diff(MxNL_Female45a))

        Phillips-Perron Unit Root Test

data:  diff(MxNL_Female45a)
Dickey-Fuller = -15.269, Truncation lag parameter = 3, p-value = 0.01

> 
> MxNTN_Female45a<-na.omit(MxNTN_Female45)
> PP.test(MxNTN_Female45a)
Error in embed(x, 2) : 'x' is not a vector or matrix
> PP.test(diff(MxNTN_Female45a))

        Phillips-Perron Unit Root Test

data:  diff(MxNTN_Female45a)
Dickey-Fuller = -26.5311, Truncation lag parameter = 3, p-value = 0.01

> 
> PP.test(MxNS_Female45)

        Phillips-Perron Unit Root Test

data:  MxNS_Female45
Dickey-Fuller = -6.6251, Truncation lag parameter = 3, p-value = 0.01

> PP.test(diff(MxNS_Female45))

        Phillips-Perron Unit Root Test

data:  diff(MxNS_Female45)
Dickey-Fuller = -18.9064, Truncation lag parameter = 3, p-value = 0.01

> 
> PP.test(MxO_Female45)

        Phillips-Perron Unit Root Test

data:  MxO_Female45
Dickey-Fuller = -5.1652, Truncation lag parameter = 3, p-value = 0.01

> PP.test(diff(MxO_Female45))

        Phillips-Perron Unit Root Test

data:  diff(MxO_Female45)
Dickey-Fuller = -23.8322, Truncation lag parameter = 3, p-value = 0.01

> 
> PP.test(MxPEI_Female45)

        Phillips-Perron Unit Root Test

data:  MxPEI_Female45
Dickey-Fuller = -8.3567, Truncation lag parameter = 3, p-value = 0.01

> PP.test(diff(MxPEI_Female45))

        Phillips-Perron Unit Root Test

data:  diff(MxPEI_Female45)
Dickey-Fuller = -20.8593, Truncation lag parameter = 3, p-value = 0.01

> 
> PP.test(MxQ_Female45)

        Phillips-Perron Unit Root Test

data:  MxQ_Female45
Dickey-Fuller = -4.328, Truncation lag parameter = 3, p-value = 0.01

> PP.test(diff(MxQ_Female45))

        Phillips-Perron Unit Root Test

data:  diff(MxQ_Female45)
Dickey-Fuller = -14.1897, Truncation lag parameter = 3, p-value = 0.01

> 
> PP.test(MxS_Female45)

        Phillips-Perron Unit Root Test

data:  MxS_Female45
Dickey-Fuller = -7.0793, Truncation lag parameter = 3, p-value = 0.01

> PP.test(diff(MxS_Female45))

        Phillips-Perron Unit Root Test

data:  diff(MxS_Female45)
Dickey-Fuller = -23.2774, Truncation lag parameter = 3, p-value = 0.01

> 
> MxY_Female45a<-na.omit(MxY_Female45)
> PP.test(MxY_Female45a)
Error in embed(x, 2) : 'x' is not a vector or matrix
> PP.test(diff(MxY_Female45a))

        Phillips-Perron Unit Root Test

data:  diff(MxY_Female45a)
Dickey-Fuller = -17.6945, Truncation lag parameter = 3, p-value = 0.01
```

I'm working out the Philips Perron test in R. Here you can see the results and I'm wondering on why pvalues come always 0,01 not only for the variable level but also at the differential level. Please some advices on what comes wrong in my codes.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation (tersely) explains it: the p-values are interpolated,
and the minimum value is 0.01.

Comment: I'm studying unit root test. The ADF test shows me that the variable are I(1). Furthermore when i see the plot of each(except for MxY_Female45a) the variables are non stationary. But by studying the Philips Perron test. I got pvalue=0,01 for all the studied variables and accordingly i should reject the null hypothesis(so variable are stationary or I(0). Please some advices on this test GIVEN THAT in theory Philips Perron Test must confirm the results explained by the ADF test(which says variables are non stationary). So the results of PP test contradicts ADF test in theory. Any help please?

Comment: Without your data, there is very little we can say. With random data, e.g., `rnorm(100)` (stationary) or `cumsum(rnorm(100))` (integrated), `adf.test`, `pp.test` and `PP.test` give consistent results.

Comment: > x<-rnorm(100) > y<-rnorm(100) > PP.test(x) Phillips-Perron Unit Root Test data: x Dickey-Fuller = -9.3286, Truncation lag parameter = 3, p-value = 0.01 > PP.test(y) Phillips-Perron Unit Root Test data: y Dickey-Fuller = -8.6662, Truncation lag parameter = 3, p-value = 0.01 I have just tried with casual data as you suggest me. I found the same result under PP.test(as you see my results above). adf.test is ok however. But the main problem lies on PP test which gives me the same results whatever data i use. Thanks. Can you replicate data above and write down the results?

Comment: For non-integrated data, `set.seed(1); x <- rnorm(100); adf.test(x)$p.value; pp.test(x)$p.value; PP.test(x)$p.value` gives `0.01` for all three tests. For integrated data, `set.seed(2); y <- cumsum(rnorm(100)); adf.test(y)$p.value; pp.test(y)$p.value; PP.test(y)$p.value` gives `0.39 0.51 0.36`.

Comment: The PP-test is a little weird because 3 diverse and casual variables produce the pvalue level. In this case given that that the test(on PP.test) provides Dickey fuller number as well. Is there any test on DF critical value we can apply to that one in order to make a significant relation. Thanks a lot for your help. I have just confirmed that i'm not wrong in my analysis at least for pvalue=0.01(We find the same pvalues for PP.test). Thanks